# WIn 8 : Node-inspector debugging url doesnt work on chrome

Tags: node-inspector

I am struggling with an issue for firing up the node inspector url.

I did `npm update` , `npm -g install node-inspector` and everything worked fine

When I type node-inspector in Command prompt then it shows

```
c:\dir>node-inspector
Node Inspector v0.10.1
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?ws=127.0.0.1:8080&port=5858 to start debugging
```

when I visit the same url on chrome it says `Webpage is not available`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yey, I got it working again.

Actually it was a problem of chrome.

```
I cleared the chrome browsing history or cache
```

Then I fired up the node-inspector and tried again and it started working again.